# Comparing the zero point vibrational energies of DCl and HCl

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

> (a) Compare the zero point energy (i.e. $E_0)$ in joules for $\ce{H^{35}Cl}$ and $\ce{D^{35}Cl}$ (assuming both are anharmonic oscillators).
>
> (b) Explain the effect this will this have on their chemistry (you may wish to use a diagram to help here).

I have calculated a value for the vibrational frequency and have a value of the anharmonicity constant for $\ce{H^{35}Cl}$ (but not the anharmonicity constant for $\ce{D^{35}Cl}).$ I am unsure on how to proceed with these as all I know is an equation linking vibrational energy to the vibrational frequency and anharmonicity constant. I would be so grateful for any insight into this.

Comment: Hint: look at the values of [H$_2$](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C1333740&Mask=1000) and [D$_2$](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7782390&Mask=1000) in the X state and see if you can find the mass scaling of $\omega_e$ and $\omega_e x_e$.

Comment: Marina, I have edited the answer a little bit, the previous answer was slightly wrong btw.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which equations you are using, but this is the one I was taught:
$$E(v)=hc\tilde{\nu}\left( v+\frac{1}{2}\right) -hc\tilde{\nu}\chi\left(v+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2.\tag{1}$$
Here, $\tilde{\nu}$ is the wavenumber of the vibration; $v$ is the quantum number that represents the vibrational levels $(v= 0, 1, 2,\ldots);$ $\chi$ is the anharmonicity constant:
$$\chi=\frac{\tilde{\nu}}{4\,D_\mathrm{e}},\tag{2}$$
where $D_\mathrm{e}$ is the depth of the lowest point of the potential well (*not* the depth of the $v = 0$ vibrational level!).

The zero-point energy is the energy when $v=0$ i.e. the molecule is in the lowest vibrational state. So you have to substitute that in the energy equation.

Now, we can assume that the well depth $(D_\mathrm{e})$ of the $\ce{H-Cl}$ and $\ce{D-Cl}$ bonds are same.

The only difference between $\ce{H-Cl}$ and $\ce{D-Cl}$ would be in the value of the vibrational wavenumber $(\tilde{\nu}),$ which you can get from the vibrational frequencies that you already have, as you wrote in the question. Once you substitute that in the equation, you will get your answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122570/discussion-on-answer-by-shoubhik-r-maiti-comparing-the-zero-point-vibrational-en).